# Make a selection based on a date

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a macro solution to the following formatting issue.

I have 2 columns in sheet1 (see attached picture); the date column and Value 1 column. I have multiple values for the same date for the whole year and I want to change the format to be as per sheet 2 (attached picture)
Basically, I want all the values of the same date to be copied and pasted in a transposed manner in the correct row on sheet 2. The selection of the values in sheet 1 should be based on the date. it would be great to have a loop that goes through the dates by increasing one day at a time.

in my own programing language, it would be:

Select range in column B where the range in column A date is equal to a specific date
copy the selection
paste transposed in sheet2
go to the next date and repeat

Thank you in advance
Regards
SamyB[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4EAi.jpg) [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXyJF.jpg)

Comment: Allow me a remark: SO expects a new question not only to include the desired behaviour, but that you describe the **core problem** or error you are confronted with by showing typically the *shortest* (i.e. `M`inimal) code (*even pseudo code*) with *all* necessary parts (i.e. `C`omplete) to reproduce the issue in a *verifiable* way (i.e. `V`erifiable). Without details what you've tried so far you risk to get no answer.  - See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with formula (in cell D2 of sheet 2): `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$99,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$99=DATE($A2,$B2,$C2)))` note that this solution requires number as month in B column

Comment: Hi I did try it but it did not work. I got the value sheet1.B2 copied all along and on the second raw I get a #calc error